# Get Windows 10 touch screen check gray on device with touch screen

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-10-upgrade, toshiba-laptop, touchscreen

On both my laptop and tablet (which each have touch screens), I see the following screen when checking the Get Windows 10 app.  Does this mean that my touch screen drivers will not work with Windows 10?  Or will my touch screens function correctly upon upgrading?

My laptop is the 2014 Toshiba Satellite Radius (Satellite P55W) and my tablet is the Dell Venue Pro 8.

[image: Get Windows 10 Info Screenshot]

Comment: That is indeed the case.  If you upgrade to a Windows 10, your touch device, will not function because the lack of a driver

Comment: @Ramhound thanks.  Didn't want to accidentally make my tablet basically unusable.  Post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

### Works for me.

> **Be sure and [create a System Image](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/4241/how-to-create-a-system-image-in-windows-7/) before installing a new operating system, see following link to find out how on your OS.**

## From Microsoft's website regarding **the preview**

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/preview-faq If you have a touch PC Insider Preview works with touch, but some things will be rough and unfinished. More touch-friendly improvements are on the way. In the meantime, let us know what it’s like to interact with Windows and apps in the preview.

## Update1

My device once showed what you posted above, it now shows this:

[image]

## Update2 08-01-2015

As I suspected my touch device works 100% A-Okay even after showing the same reports you had previously posted.  Hope you enjoy Windows 10.

[image]
This is the production release shown here.

- touch click **works**
- touch hold click for right **works**
- touch writing **works**
- touch erasing **works**
- pen hover pointer **works**
- pen writing **works**
- pen first and second buttons **work**
- Synaptics touch pad drivers ported right over and **work**

## Update3 08-03-2015: Clean install of Windows 10 had driver issues

Although I was able to install an update to Windows 10 from 8.1 that seemed to work seemlessly, I quickly tried a fresh clean install from a Win10 ISO USB.   This is where drivers started to fail and although everything else worked fine, my keyboard quit working.  On Sony's website they have a disclaimer to not update until after August when they have finished testing their devices.  I'm stating this because each manufacture might be different.  For instance my brother installed 10 on his RAZOR laptop and he reported they already had drivers ready for windows 10.

> Note: I was able to restore to my working 8.1 system and do the update to win 10 again because [I created an image as you should before a major upgrade.](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/4241/how-to-create-a-system-image-in-windows-7/)

Again, I hope this info is helpful.

Comment: Besides your opinion do you have any facts to backup your statement? A device will not work without a device driver, and there are no, Windows 10 drivers for the touch device for the author's device

Comment: Just because it works with Windows 8 doesn't mean it works with Windows 10.  The driver programming model changed, so the drivers are not inherently backward compatible like they were between Windows 8 and 8.1

Comment: Thanks for downvoting after I did my research.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/preview-faq


If you have a touch PC

Insider Preview works with touch, but some things will be rough and unfinished. More touch-friendly improvements are on the way. In the meantime, let us know what it’s like to interact with Windows and apps in the preview.

Comment: Your comment should really be the answer.  I suspect the downvote is because the answer conflicts with Microsoft's advice, plus you state an opinion (unfounded, contrary to MS advice, and answers should be factual, not opinion).  Consider editing your answer to reflect Microsoft's advice.